# How do I use Drush 8 site aliases in Drush 9?

Tags: drush

In Drush 8, my site aliases are loaded correctly from `~/.drush/mysite.aliases.drushrc.php`.

E.g.

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/html/mysite.dev/docroot',
  'uri' => 'mysite.prod.acquia-sites.com',
  'remote-host' => 'mysite.ssh.acquia-sites.com',
  'remote-user' => 'mysite.dev',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%drush-script' => 'drush' . $drush_major_version,
  ),
);
```

However these aliases aren't loaded in Drush 9.

```
$ drush site-alias
{  }
```

How I should define site aliases in Drush 9? Is there any migration process?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aliases are now provided in YAML files. According to the [example aliases file for Drush 9](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.site.yml):

> To convert legacy alias (`*.aliases.drushrc.php`) to yml, run the site:alias-convert command.

So running the command:

```
drush site:alias-convert
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Also note that alias discovery locations are more limited by default in 9.

Comment: updated link, https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.site.yml

Comment: running this generated the yml files, but they are empty for some reason.

Comment: Here is a bit more detailed breakdown of the steps needed to get drush 9 aliases working. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252751/aliases-stop-working-after-composer-install/252775#252775

Comment: Not sure how much the original aliases.drushrc.php influences this. Mine had three aliases in it (dev, staging, production), which generated three files, which only pertained to the local, but one had all three. I split these then according to my three builds, and deleted the rest, which is now working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Clive's answer is a start, but as TheRealWebGuy notes, there is another step you must take.

I was upgrading from drush 8 to drush 9, and my aliases still did not work after running  `drush site:alias-convert`. [An additional step](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/252775/1441) that I needed to take for my new alias files to work was to run `drush init`. I ran it in my user home directory; I don't know if that matters.

Hopefully this saves future users some additional clicking and searching.

Comment: `drush init` copies the local (project) configurations to your global (machine) drush configurations at `~/.drush`. Do this if you want global aliases.